# subprocess.Popen raises error while command works in shell

Tags: python, subprocess

### Issue

I have this command, which works in the shell:

```bash
<ABS_PATH>/odbc2parquet query --connection-string "Driver={<DRIVER_NAME>};SERVER=<SERVER_IP>,<SERVER_PORT>;DATABASE=<DB_NAME>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<PWD>" <OUTPUT_PATH> "<QUERY>"
```

But the following python code doesn't work:

```py
import subprocess
from typing import List

cmd_odbc: List[str] = [
    "<ABS_PATH>/odbc2parquet",
    "query",
    "--connection-string",
    '"Driver={<DRIVER_NAME>};SERVER=<SERVER_IP>,<SERVER_PORT>;DATABASE=<DB_NAME>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<PWD>"',
    "<OUTPUT_PATH>",
    '"<QUERY>"'
]
process_odbc: subprocess.Popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd_odbc)
process_odbc.wait()
```

This raises the following error:

```
Error: ODBC emitted an error calling 'SQLDriverConnect':
State: IM002, Native error: 0, Message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Instead, I have to do the following workaround

```py
import subprocess
from typing import List

cmd_odbc: List[str] = [
    "<ABS_PATH>/odbc2parquet",
    "query",
    "--connection-string",
    '"Driver={<DRIVER_NAME>};SERVER=<SERVER_IP>,<SERVER_PORT>;DATABASE=<DB_NAME>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<PWD>"',
    "<OUTPUT_PATH>",
    '"<QUERY>"'
]
process_odbc: subprocess.Popen = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(cmd_odbc), shell=True)
process_odbc.wait()
```

### Question

Why doesn't the first code work while the second does? What is the main difference here?

Thanks to everyone reading.

Comment: Those double-quotes around two of the parameters in the shell version aren't actually being passed on to the command; they're just ensuring that the contents get passed as a single parameter, even if they contain spaces or other characters that are meaningful to the shell.  You shouldn't have them in your Python code - having them as separate items in the list is all you need to do to make them unambiguous.

Comment: In `shell=True` those inner quotes can be necessary, but with `shell=True` you're completely defeating the benefits and purpose of using a list in the first place. Take out the quotes, and stick to the default `shell=False`.